# Hibernate marker interface mapping using jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, interface, mapping, marker

Hi I am new to hibernate and am facing problem in mapping marker interface. 
I have a marker interface.

```
    public interface Item{}
```

Then there are two classes which implement this interface:

```
    public class Hotel implements Item{
         private int id;
         private String name;
         private String location;
         .......
    }
    public class Restaurant implements Item{
         private int id;
         private String name; 
         private String cuisine;
         ....... 
    }
```

There is another class which uses these two classes:

```
    public class ItineraryItem {
          private int id;
          private Item item;
    }
```

How can I map these classes using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Item {
     @Id
     private int id;
}

@Entity
public class Hotel extends Item {
     @Column
     private String name;
     @Column
     private String location;
}

@Entity
public class Restaurant extends Item {
     @Column
     private String name; 
     @Column
     private String cuisine;
}

@Entity
public class ItineraryItem {
      @Id
      private int id;
      @JoinColumn
      private Item item;
}
```

`InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS` will cause `Hotel` and `Restaurant` to have their own separate tables.

You can find more information here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance

Comment: `Item` is no longer a marker interface with this. There is really no need to map the `Item` if it has no methods.